# How do I get a div to overflow without pushing other content down in an email in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am trying to place a div in an email such that it overflows later-placed divs that are inline-block (instead of pushing them down), by virtue of the fact that the div in question is display:inline.  It seems to be working in Chrome, but I can't get it to render correctly in IE, where it gets bounded by an inline-block div placed later.

Here is an example of what I am talking about (with the div in question having a blue background):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
div {
    *display: inline!important;
    _height: 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 1px; display: block!important; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;">
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 1px; display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 10px; background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 1px; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 280px; background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; width: 280px; height: 280px; background-color: red; line-height: 23px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, FreeSans, san0serif; color: #333;">
      <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0; width: 150px; height: 320px; background-color: blue; display: block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 280px; background-color: gray;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 10px; background-color: gray;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how  it renders in Chrome (and how I would expect it to render):
[image: Correct]

This is how it renders in IE(8):

[image: Incorrect]

How do I get IE to render this div like it does in Chrome?

Comment: overflow: visible might do the trick.

Comment: That's the default, and even if I try to override it it doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients do not listen 100% consistently to css. This can also hold true to some extent for web client email views. you would need to decouple the 2 divs from the container object. IE : two separate contains so when the one of the left overflows - the righthand div does not.

edit : Here's a good compatibility map : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating the red and blue divs? This removes them from the flow of the document and if relatively positioned and z indexed properly should display like you want.